# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit Binder concurrency

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have one consumer microservice that handles messages from other producer microservice. I managed event driven structure with Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMq  Binder.
I want to limit maximum concurrent messages to be consumed by consumer microservice. I mean in case producer sends 7 messages, if I limit maximum number of messages to be consumed to 5. I expect first 5 messages consumed by Consumer microservice. If any of message processing is completed, I expect to consume 6 th message.  I tried to manage this with RabbitMq consumer property "max-concurreny:5" , it did not work.

In case if 2 Consumer Microservices are running and  max-concurrency to 5, I expect that each consumer microservice should consume at most 5 message. They should consume 10 message at total. Also messages should be distributed between Microservice in an balanced way.

This is my binder configuration in application.yml

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: admin
    password: admin
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.jdbc.DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration
  application:
    name: simulationService
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: functionRouter
    stream:
      function:
        routing:
          enabled: true
      bindings:
        callBack-out-0:
          destination: simulation-workflow
          content-type: application/json
          group: workflow
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: simulation
          content-type: application/json
          group: simulation
      rabbit:
        bindings:
           functionRouter:
             consumer:
               max-concurrency: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`concurrency = 5` means each instance will get 5 consumers; each consumer has a `prefetch` property (default 250 in Spring AMQP, 1 in spring-cloud-stream), which will affect message distribution.

1 should provide even distribution across consumers, but at the cost of performance.

There is no way to "limit" a consumer to only 5 messages, but `prefetch = 5` might do what you are looking for.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

> **prefetch**

> Prefetch count.

> Default: 1.

Comment: Hello Gary. I did not get your solution exactly. Does it work if I define concurrency to 5 and prefetch 1 or I should define prefetch to 5 without concurrency for each Consumer service? How can I achieve to  expected behaniour?

Comment: Each message processing operation can take 50 seconds. It seems consumer directly sends ack message without completing all processing of message. That is why new message is directly consumed without waiting overall process. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Messages are not ack’d until the listener exits. It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do but `concurrency=1` with `prefetch=5` means that 5 messages will be outstanding at any time at each instance. When a message is processed (and ack'd) the next message is sent so there are still 5 outstanding.